# After a photon passes through the phase shifter, does it gain the geometric phase or dynamical phase?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-optics

In Quantum Mechanics, the phase can be divided into geometric phase and dynamical phase. In mach-zehnder interferometer, after the photon passes through the phase shifter, what kind of phase does it gain? The geometric one or the dynamical one?  Geometric phase is the phase like [Berry Phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_phase), and there are [differences](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369245/difference-between-dynamical-and-geometric-phase) between them.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by geometric and dynamic phases?

Comment: I've added some basic definitions to my question.

Comment: can you clarify how you're defining "geometric" and "dynamical" phases in this context? As far as I know, you need some type of time-dependent dynamics to talk of geometric phases, and to define a loop in some parametric space for the dynamical phase. What would that correspond to for a MZ interferometer?

Comment: I'm just thinking, any phase in wave function can be divided into geometric phase and dynamic phase. And since after a photon passes through the phase shifter, it gains a phase. So can the phase be divided into one of them, i.e., geometry or dynamic?

Comment: I beleive not, the division of phases into geometric and dynamical is inapplicable to photon in Mach-Zehnder interferometer.

Comment: @kludg But from this [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369735), the phase can always be divided into the geometrical part and dynamical part, and since the photon is a quantum object, the phase of it should be divided so.